# Is there a general build process in aptana studio 3?

Tags: build-process, build-automation, aptana, aptana3

For example, I'm working in a JavaScript project and I have split what is ment to be a single file into multiple files to ease the development process. Now is there some kind of tool/process that would let me join this and maybe compress into a new single file automatically or as part of a build process?

Comment: When would you like to combine the file?

Comment: Probably on demand, on a button press of command. I've been looking into a git hook for this...